# Should I use Entry's .get() or its textvariable's for Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code is something like:

```
myVar = StringVar()
myEntry = Entry(master, textvariable=myVar)
```

So when I need to retrieve input from `myEntry`, should I use

```
myText = myVar.get()
```

or

```
myText = myEntry.get()
```

Is there a better way ? (and why?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are doing traces on the StringVars, I say stick with using the `get` method and don't create StringVars. Using the `get` method removes complexity -- one less object to maintain and one less object to take up space in memory (multiplied by however many times you use StringVars in your application).

Sure, it's an imperceptible amount of overhead,  but all things being equal, the less complex solution is usually the best. Why add a variable that allows you to do what you can already do without the variable?

Comment: So you are saying that I don't need `textvariable=myVar` when creating the Entry?

Comment: @BryanOakley did you mean without the use of text variable also we can go for myEntry.  So if we need to display the same result in another tkinter object, how are we supposed to do it?

Comment: @algosig: I don't quite understand your question. If you want to tie two or more widgets together (ie: display the exact same data), using a `StringVar` is the right choice -- this is almost exactly what it's designed for. Most uses of an entry widget don't have that requirement, so you don't need to use a `StringVar`. You still have access to the data either way.

Comment: @BryanOakley i used the stringvar like this:-  entry1 = Entry(root,text='username', textvariable=myentry1) 
  and assigned anothe label where I used the previous textvariable myentry1 like this :- label1=Label(root,text='User Entered is ', textvariable=myentry1).grid() , Shouldnot it display  entry field's value is the  label whose text variable is same?

Comment: @algosig: The label won't do what you think it does. If you use both `text` and `textvariable`, the value of `text` is ignored.

Comment: Also consider when using `validatecommand=` to verify the entered data AND using a `StringVar()` a **.set()** on that `StringVar` won't trigger your `validatecommand` handler function.

I just noticed that little odd behavior and now go back to this little more ugly **.delete()** + **.insert()** implementation to set the text of a Tkinter Entry