# Tkinter fails to pass Entry data between two functions

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

When I run the following code, I receive the following error: NameError: name 'barE' is not defined.

Does Tkinter's Entry work from one function to another?  I have a global window and frame in this program and it passes the user's input without error using the same syntax as below.

```
def newSearchForm():
    window2=Tk()
    window2.geometry("650x400")
    frame = Frame(window2)
    frame.pack(side="top", expand=True, fill="both")
    
    barcode=Label(frame,text="Please Enter The Barcode", font='time 15')
    barcode.place(x=10,y=90)
    barE=Entry(frame)
    barE.place(x=250,y=90)

    isbn=Label(frame,text="Please Enter The ISBN", font='time 15')
    isbn.place(x=10,y=130)
    isbE=Entry(frame)
    isbE.place(x=250,y=130)
    
    repeatSearchButton=Button(frame,text="Enter", command=newSearch,width=12,bg='gray')
    repeatSearchButton.place(x=150,y=170)
    
    window.mainloop()

def newSearch():
    uB = barE.get()
    uI = isbE.get()
    carlSearch(uB, uI)
    itemTitle=workspace.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div').text
    ingramSearch()
    fantasticFictionSearch(itemTitle)
    outputMetadata()
```

I tried using the lambda command to explicitly pass the variables and that didn't work.
I tried using anexising window and that didn't work, so I destroyed it and created a new one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use text variable. You can create a text variable by `StringVar` and assign it in the entry widget.

For more details on why to use text variable see [Should I use Entry's .get() or its textvariable's for Tkinter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169258/should-i-use-entrys-get-or-its-textvariables-for-tkinter-in-python)

Usage:

```
barE_var=StringVar()
barE=Entry(frame,textvariable=barE_var)
barE.place(x=250,y=90)
```

To get value use `barE_var.get()`.

*Does Tkinter's Entry work from one function to another?*

It does work, but have to use global keyword to access them.

```
def newSearch():
    global barE_var
```

Comment: _"The Entry widget does'nt have any function named get. "_ - this is completely false. So is this: _"To get value from Entry, you have to use text variable."_.

Comment: @BryanOakley , thanks for the correction, i just got to know entry widget does have .get method. :)

Comment: @BryanOakley , would you like to help me regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546744/applying-liveserver-logic-for-tkinter-file